# Remove commits from master again

Tags: git, git-merge

I commit all my stuff to special branches like feature/1234. A feature that we thought it is already done was then merged to master.
This feature needs to go back to development again, but there are other commits in master which need to go live now.

How can I get these single commits out of master and still keep them in feature/1234?

EDIT: the commits from feature/1234 are not the latest ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit after understanding the problem**

[git rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) is your friend. Just run `git rebase -i commit-id` where `commit-id` is the one previous to the three you want to remove, then, when the default editor will open, simply delete the three commits you do not want on master, save and close.

**Old version, misunderstood**
<strike>If I understood, you should have no problem with your second request: the commit is still in `feature/1234` if you have not deleted the branch.

As for the first request, remove the commit, just run
`git reset --hard HEAD~1` which will move the `HEAD` back one commit.

If you want to go back to a specific commit by its id, you can run `git reset --hard commit-id`.

For more info about reset: http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html and https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html</strike>

Comment: this works locally for me, buuuut I can't push it :( any ideas?

Comment: `git push -f`, forces push to remote. However, mind the note by Magnus! If you think any of your co-worker has pulled the wrong master, you should asked them to [force-pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854332/git-pull-says-already-up-to-date-after-undoing-a-git-pull/19855921#19855921) to clean their history. Sorry for the delay, I was in a meeting

Answer (score 2):

If you can rebase your branch, then that's sometimes the cleanest way of removing acommit - all traces of it will be gone. The disadvantage is that any branch taken from your master branch between the time the offending commit got in and the time when you remove the commit will have histories that have diverged with the master. If you can't guarantee that this has not happened (e.g. if you have published your repo to others), then it's probably bette to revert the commit using `git revert`. That wil produce a new commit on top of your master which undoes the changes of the old one. History thus keeps going forward, and sub-branches can simply rebase to the lastest as usual.

Comment: +1 for the note `If you can rebase your branch` which I forgot in my answer